# My Eclipse IDE keeps crashing -

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, ide

when i try exporting some of my projects i get this from the ADT Problem Report, some of it:
im trying to make a facebook app, how do you combine projects Without the ads crashing.

i need more details because my post looks like code only.. but its the only thing i have to provide information on why in the world my ide keeps crashing..

```
Process:         eclipse [626]
Path:            /Users/Tahj182/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-1/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:      org.eclipse.eclipse
Version:         3.8 (3.8)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [142]

Date/Time:       2013-05-15 01:04:23.870 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          -678 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           12
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  -3870 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   11
Anonymous UUID:                      B20A49CF-060D-4A4D-8602-227B8007795A

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000a, 0x000000015c1d325b
Crashed Thread:  33  Java: ModalContext
Kenter code here
Application Specific Information:

Java information:
 Exception type: Bus Error (0xa) at pc=0x000000010079f930

 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01-101 mixed mode macosx-amd64)

Current thread (0x000000011327a000):  JavaThread "ModalContext" [_thread_in_native, id=1595817984, stack(0x000000015f0e4000,0x000000015f1e4000)]
Stack: [0x000000015f0e4000,0x000000015f1e4000]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(JLjava/lang/String;Z)J
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+34
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+5
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(Ljava/io/File;)Z+118
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(Ljava/io/File;Z)Z+48
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process()Z+15
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Ljava/lang/String;)Z+18
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles()Z+100
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Lcom/android/dx/command/dexer/Main$Arguments;)I+84
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Collection;ZZLjava/io/PrintStream;Ljava/io/PrintStream;)I+349
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)V+340
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/security/PrivateKey;Ljava/security/cert/X509Certificate;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+853
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z+269
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(Lcom/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/wizards/export/ExportWizard;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z+2
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+10
j  org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run()V+15
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000000011327a000 JavaThread "ModalContext" [_thread_in_native, id=1595817984, stack(0x000000015f0e4000,0x000000015f1e4000)]
  0x00000001131bb800 JavaThread "Thread-20" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1589751808, stack(0x000000015eb9b000,0x000000015ec1b000)]
  0x0000000113622000 JavaThread "Worker-30" [_thread_blocked, id=1639288832, stack(0x0000000161a59000,0x0000000161b59000)]
  0x00000001132b8000 JavaThread "Worker-29" [_thread_blocked, id=1634742272, stack(0x0000000161603000,0x0000000161703000)]
  0x000000015fb3f800 JavaThread "Worker-28" [_thread_blocked, id=1635815424, stack(0x0000000161709000,0x0000000161809000)]
  0x000000015b3ff800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegionProcessor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1597001728, stack(0x000000015f205000,0x000000015f305000)]
  0x000000015ff97800 JavaThread "Worker-27" [_thread_blocked, id=1586380800, stack(0x000000015e7e4000,0x000000015e8e4000)]
  0x0000000113359800 JavaThread "Worker-26" [_thread_blocked, id=1541431296, stack(0x000000015bd06000,0x000000015be06000)]
  0x000000015b66e800 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1648279552, stack(0x00000001622ec000,0x00000001623ec000)]
  0x000000011324a800 JavaThread "Worker-16" [_thread_in_native, id=1637670912, stack(0x00000001618ce000,0x00000001619ce000)]
  0x000000015b408800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1627062272, stack(0x0000000160eb0000,0x0000000160fb0000)]
  0x000000015b643800 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1592860672, stack(0x000000015ee12000,0x000000015ef12000)]
  0x0000000113210800 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1594757120, stack(0x000000015efe1000,0x000000015f0e1000)]
  0x000000015b438000 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=1563664384, stack(0x000000015d23a000,0x000000015d33a000)]
  0x000000015b4b3800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1561710592, stack(0x000000015d05d000,0x000000015d15d000)]
  0x000000015b2a8800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1559588864, stack(0x000000015ce57000,0x000000015cf57000)]
  0x000000015b2a7800 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1557725184, stack(0x000000015cc90000,0x000000015cd90000)]
  0x000000015b4b8800 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1556664320, stack(0x000000015cb8d000,0x000000015cc8d000)]
  0x000000015b386800 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=1555603456, stack(0x000000015ca8a000,0x000000015cb8a000)]
  0x00000001130a0000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1537228800, stack(0x000000015b904000,0x000000015ba04000)]
  0x000000015b016800 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1536167936, stack(0x000000015b801000,0x000000015b901000)]
  0x000000011309f800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1526091776, stack(0x000000015ae65000,0x000000015af65000)]
  0x000000011309e800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1525030912, stack(0x000000015ad62000,0x000000015ae62000)]
  0x000000011309e000 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (CMS)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1523970048, stack(0x000000015ac5f000,0x000000015ad5f000)]
  0x000000015b006800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1522909184, stack(0x000000015ab5c000,0x000000015ac5c000)]
  0x0000000113097000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1521848320, stack(0x000000015aa59000,0x000000015ab59000)]
  0x0000000113000800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1889012928, stack(0x00007fff5f400000,0x00007fff5fc00000)]
Other Threads:
  0x0000000113096800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000015a956000,0x000000015aa56000] [id=1520787456]
  0x000000015b017000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000015ba07000,0x000000015bb07000] [id=1538289664]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)
VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 par new generation   total 18624K, used 3157K [0x0000000116b10000, 0x0000000117fd0000, 0x00000001194a0000)
  eden space 16000K,   7% used [0x0000000116b10000, 0x0000000116c35258, 0x0000000117ab0000)
  from space 2624K,  75% used [0x0000000117ab0000, 0x0000000117ca04f0, 0x0000000117d40000)
  to   space 2624K,   0% used [0x0000000117d40000, 0x0000000117d40000, 0x0000000117fd0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 129332K, used 100681K [0x00000001194a0000, 0x00000001212ed000, 0x0000000146b10000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 155108K, used 99605K [0x0000000146b10000, 0x0000000150289000, 0x0000000156b10000)

Virtual Machine Arguments:
JVM Args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts -Xms40m -Xmx768m -Xdock:icon=../Resources/adt.icns -XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts -Declipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
Java Command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic
Physical Memory: Page Size = 4k, Total = 2048M, Free = 123M


Thread 24:  Java: Worker-16
0   libzip.jnilib                   0x00000001007a4314 Java_java_util_zip_Deflater_deflateBytes + 654
1   ???                             0x00000001139156a8 0 + 4623259304
2   ???                             0x000000011390992e 0 + 4623210798
3   ???                             0x000000011390992e 0 + 4623210798
4   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
5   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
6   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
7   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
8   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
9   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
10  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
11  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
12  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
13  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
14  ???                             0x0000000113909973 0 + 4623210867
15  ???                             0x0000000113909cf4 0 + 4623211764
16  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
17  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
18  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
19  ???                             0x0000000113909cf4 0 + 4623211764
20  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
21  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
22  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
23  ???                             0x0000000113909973 0 + 4623210867
24  ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
25  ???                             0x0000000113909973 0 + 4623210867
26  ???                             0x00000001139043f1 0 + 4623188977
27  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278dc1d JVM_Lseek + 156985
28  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278da15 JVM_Lseek + 156465
29  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bc57 JVM_InternString + 1459
30  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bb4c JVM_InternString + 1192
31  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bab5 JVM_InternString + 1041
32  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b953 JVM_InternString + 687
33  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b607 JVM_StartThread + 1211
34  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270b4e8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 41410
35  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502afd6 _pthread_start + 331
36  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502ae89 thread_start + 13

Thread 25:  Java: [ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff1d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff23ed mach_msg + 59
2   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270bc9b JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 43381
3   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270bb70 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 43082
4   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279d048 JVM_MonitorWait + 3976
5   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c3a6 JVM_MonitorWait + 742
6   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c16b JVM_MonitorWait + 171
7   ???                             0x00000001139156a8 0 + 4623259304
8   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
9   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
10  ???                             0x00000001139043f1 0 + 4623188977
11  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278dc1d JVM_Lseek + 156985
12  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278da15 JVM_Lseek + 156465
13  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bc57 JVM_InternString + 1459
14  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bb4c JVM_InternString + 1192
15  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bab5 JVM_InternString + 1041
16  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b953 JVM_InternString + 687
17  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b607 JVM_StartThread + 1211
18  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270b4e8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 41410
19  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502afd6 _pthread_start + 331
20  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502ae89 thread_start + 13

Thread 26:  Java: Worker-26
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff1d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff23ed mach_msg + 59
2   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270bd50 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 43562
3   libclient.dylib                 0x00000001127252bd jio_vsnprintf + 22655
4   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279cd53 JVM_MonitorWait + 3219
5   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c3a6 JVM_MonitorWait + 742
6   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c16b JVM_MonitorWait + 171
7   ???                             0x00000001139156a8 0 + 4623259304
8   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
9   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
10  ???                             0x0000000113909973 0 + 4623210867
11  ???                             0x00000001139043f1 0 + 4623188977
12  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278dc1d JVM_Lseek + 156985
13  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278da15 JVM_Lseek + 156465
14  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bc57 JVM_InternString + 1459
15  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bb4c JVM_InternString + 1192
16  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bab5 JVM_InternString + 1041
17  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b953 JVM_InternString + 687
18  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b607 JVM_StartThread + 1211
19  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270b4e8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 41410
20  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502afd6 _pthread_start + 331
21  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502ae89 thread_start + 13

Thread 27:  Java: Worker-27
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff1d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff23ed mach_msg + 59
2   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270bd50 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 43562
3   libclient.dylib                 0x00000001127252bd jio_vsnprintf + 22655
4   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279cd53 JVM_MonitorWait + 3219
5   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c3a6 JVM_MonitorWait + 742
6   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c16b JVM_MonitorWait + 171
7   ???                             0x00000001139156a8 0 + 4623259304
8   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
9   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
10  ???                             0x0000000113909973 0 + 4623210867
11  ???                             0x00000001139043f1 0 + 4623188977
12  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278dc1d JVM_Lseek + 156985
13  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278da15 JVM_Lseek + 156465
14  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bc57 JVM_InternString + 1459
15  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bb4c JVM_InternString + 1192
16  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bab5 JVM_InternString + 1041
17  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b953 JVM_InternString + 687
18  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b607 JVM_StartThread + 1211
19  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270b4e8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 41410
20  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502afd6 _pthread_start + 331
21  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502ae89 thread_start + 13

Thread 28:  Java: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegio
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff1d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff23ed mach_msg + 59
2   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270bd50 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 43562
3   libclient.dylib                 0x00000001127252bd jio_vsnprintf + 22655
4   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279cd53 JVM_MonitorWait + 3219
5   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c3a6 JVM_MonitorWait + 742
6   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c16b JVM_MonitorWait + 171
7   ???                             0x00000001139156a8 0 + 4623259304
8   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
9   ???                             0x00000001139043f1 0 + 4623188977
10  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278dc1d JVM_Lseek + 156985
11  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278da15 JVM_Lseek + 156465
12  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bc57 JVM_InternString + 1459
13  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bb4c JVM_InternString + 1192
14  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bab5 JVM_InternString + 1041
15  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b953 JVM_InternString + 687
16  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b607 JVM_StartThread + 1211
17  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270b4e8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 41410
18  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502afd6 _pthread_start + 331
19  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502ae89 thread_start + 13

Thread 29:  Java: Worker-28
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff1d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84ff23ed mach_msg + 59
2   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270bd50 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 43562
3   libclient.dylib                 0x00000001127252bd jio_vsnprintf + 22655
4   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279cd53 JVM_MonitorWait + 3219
5   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c3a6 JVM_MonitorWait + 742
6   libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279c16b JVM_MonitorWait + 171
7   ???                             0x00000001139156a8 0 + 4623259304
8   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
9   ???                             0x000000011390981a 0 + 4623210522
10  ???                             0x0000000113909973 0 + 4623210867
11  ???                             0x00000001139043f1 0 + 4623188977
12  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278dc1d JVM_Lseek + 156985
13  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011278da15 JVM_Lseek + 156465
14  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bc57 JVM_InternString + 1459
15  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bb4c JVM_InternString + 1192
16  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279bab5 JVM_InternString + 1041
17  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b953 JVM_InternString + 687
18  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011279b607 JVM_StartThread + 1211
19  libclient.dylib                 0x000000011270b4e8 JNI_CreateJavaVM_Impl + 41410
20  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502afd6 _pthread_start + 331
21  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8502ae89 thread_start + 13

Thread 33 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem on MacOSX. To export a project:

1. Uncheck Project/Build Automatically
2. Project/Clean (clean all related library projects as well)
3. Export

Comment: it makes the imports not work right, well just the facebook imports... and some stuff like session, sessionstate, and request

Comment: but i just want to say that its people like you @323go that make the world a better place.. i mean this question is for like the genius bar at the mac store, or geek squad at best buy.. all of the problems i've been having with this quirky computer language and the issues it gives my computer has been a big puzzle for me.. thank you sir and the creaters of stackoverflow.. THANK YOU For Your Help!

Comment: Wow, you're happy :) Glad I could help a little... sorry I couldn't solve your problem. I'm using apps with ActionBarSherlock and other imports, and this got it working.

Comment: actionbarsherlock.. the thing about android.. or when you're a noob,  is that when I  implement a new feature, like airpush and leadbolt.. its hard to add something else to the app because it's almost like you have to build the app from scratch when you want to add facebook.. i can't seem to figure out how to combine projects.. check this out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570778/session-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-eclipse-keeps-crashing i posted that minutes after you first comment.. i can't get past my request and sessionstate type stuff, they become unlinked or something..

Comment: i'm going to have to figure out what action bar sherlock is.. but if someone could please answer this quEstion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570778/session-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-eclipse-keeps-crashing the build path becomes untangled or broken down when i uncheck build automatically. so how do i custom build the facebook stuff like session and sessionState like it does when i choose to build it automatically?

Comment: ActionbarSherlock (google it) is a compatibility library for Android which makes it very easy to use ICS features in older Android versions. The reason I mentioned it is not (as I might have mistyped) that it fixes the issue, but simply that my MacOSX exports from Eclipse work fine even with major libraries, such as ABS. I don't know whether this makes a difference, but before exporting signed apps for release, I always "clean" all related projects, and "Build Automatically" is usually disabled on Library Projects anyways for me.